# What does the use of copyFor() in javaFX

Tags: java, methods, javafx, keyevent

I've searched on online and didn't found any clear explanation about the use of copyFor() method in javaFX which is often used on keyEvent.copyFor(event.getSource(), event.getTarget()). This method used on following code.

```
private KeyEvent remap(KeyEvent event) 
      {
        KeyEvent newEvent = new KeyEvent(
            event.getEventType(),
            event.getCharacter(),
            event.getText(),
            event.getCode(),
            !event.isShiftDown(),
            event.isControlDown(),
            event.isAltDown(),
            event.isMetaDown()
        );

        return newEvent.copyFor(event.getSource(), event.getTarget());
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation:

> Creates and returns a copy of this event with the specified event source and target.

This means it copies the event handler to a new source and target. A possible use for this is if you wanted a key combination to perform a specific event on two different nodes.